# Find the basis of U+W (which are matrix subspaces)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I usually know how to find a basis of u+v when the case scenario is vectors.

Now the case scenario is matrices(Real Numbers) $3\times2$ and I'm confused.

The image describes the basis of $U$ and $W$ and I need to calculate $U+W$ and I don't know how..

If it helps I Found that the dimension of the intersection of the bases is $1$.

so the Dimension of $U+W$ should be $5$.

[image: Description :]

any hints ?

Comment: Please typeset with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Write each vector in these bases as (row-)vectors with coordinates w.r.t. the standard basis:
$$E_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\enspace E_2=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\enspace E_3=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\enspace\text{&c.}$$
and perform row reduction on the resulting matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&-1&1&-1\\1&-2&0&0&2&2 \\1&0&1&-1&0&-4 \\ 1&-1&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&1&-1&0&0 \\0&0&0&0&1&-1\end{pmatrix}$$